# Ruby audio APIs

Tags: ruby, audio, rubygems

I'm working on a simple musical instrument tuner in Ruby (2.0.0) using GTK. When it comes to audio playback though, I don't know where to start looking for a suitable gem. Any recommendations? My idea was to package audio files of the 12 notes of the chromatic scale, but I can't seem to find audio samples of these.

I should also say that I'd much prefer if it was cross-platform!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it can help you, but the only one I came across is [this one](https://github.com/warhammerkid/ruby-audio)
It's based on [libsndfile](http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/)

You might also wanna checkout [this simple audio player using GTK](http://ruby-gnome2.sourceforge.jp/?Simple%20Audio%20Player) on SouceForge.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that out. I've also found Rubygame which has an audio API using SDL. Would it be standard for an application to check for a library such as libsndfile, regardless of the platform? As in, should my Ruby program explicitly check for that library and prompt user to install it if not present?

Comment: No, the library should be install on your server (your computer for development, and your host machine, like Heroku or such for production). Ruby will take care of using it so that it's transparent for the client